# Create iOS Development Certificate - Invalid Certificate - for team

Tags: iphone, ios, ios-provisioning, iphone-developer-program

I want to create a developer certificate on apple developer account. My supervisor invite me to their team. I accepted.

I opened iOS Provisioning Portal and clicked to "Request Certificate" button on certificates tab. i performed "How to create a development certificate" rules step by step about keychain. And choose the CSR file and submit it on safari, firefox, chrome browsers. I performed all these actions on Certificates->Development page. The result is :

```
Create iOS Development Certificate

Invalid Certificate
```

But when i used Certificates->Distribution page to create a certificate, i am ok.

Is this problem a general problem? But, all the articles, questions say same things about this situation:

- open keychain
- Choose Keychain Access > Certificate Assistant > Request a Certificate from a Certificate       Authority
- In the Certificate Information window, enter or select the following information
- The Certificate Assistant saves a Certificate Signing Request (CSR) file to your Desktop
- At the end, submit it.

But the apple is not accept my request file. I am trying on MacOSx 10.6.8. Keychain version is 4.1.1. My safari version is Version 5.1.2 (6534.52.7). My XCode version is Version 4.2 and Build 4C199.

I read this page http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Testing_iOS_4_Apps_on_the_iPhone_–_Developer_Certificates_and_Provisioning_Profiles to get help. I never seen this page: http://www.techotopia.com/images/2/22/IPhoneCertificatePendingApproval.png

I know, there are lots of page about these problem. I searched it many times and read many page. But i did not solve. Does anyone have a suggestion?

Comment: have you set the same mail, which you use when login into dev center,  when you create certificate?

Comment: yes, it is same mail address and I tried same name, exactly.

Comment: i try to create a certificate w8 :)

Comment: w8, If you do not have the WWDR intermediate certificate installed, click here to download now. have you got it?

Comment: have you created an app ID before request certificate?

Comment: i download wwdr certificate and install it but it is named as "iPhone Distribution" on keychain->Certificates tab. Yes i create an appID.

Comment: i download wwdr certificate from iOS Privision Portal->Certificate->Development tab. i did not download from Distribution tab.

Comment: i want to test my application on device. Xcode say me this when i run the application:

"Code Sign error: The identity 'iPhone Developer' doesn't match any valid certificate/private key pair in the default keychain"

Does this mean, i must use developer certificate to test on device?

Comment: you have to create provisioning profile, so download it and drag in xcode icon on dock ;)

Comment: yes distribution is only for release, if you want to test on device you must have developer certificate

Comment: how can i make developer certificate under this conditions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wrote my long company name which has got many turkish character when register to apple developer program. In fact, apple say me, "You write your company name completely." and I did it. After that, I created a CSR code and I tried to send it to Apple. But CSR code did not pair. Because my company name has some turkish character and company name did not pair with my saved company name by Apple.

Solution : I send an email to apple to change my Company name. At the end, it worked.

Answer (score 2):

I encountered this "Invalid Certificate" issue yesterday when I try to enable push for our app and got it solved.

the reason is,

in dev portal, there is already a distribution cert existing. this cert was applied by a previous member. He transferred  his private key (.p12) to me, making my Mac book can develop codes. so I guess 1 private key can only apply for 1 type of distribution cert(inhouse,adhoc,Appstore). if I don't delete old one, and upload my CSR directly to portal, portal will say "invalid certificate". After delete it, works!

hope can help you a little.

Comment: ov, sorry. You are right. But my problem is my company name is too long and there are more turkish character. And the certificate not accept these caharacter and they did not pair. i am writing now my solution.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your solution. It is interesting.

Answer (score 0):

I got this invalid certificate issue when there were already two active distribution certificates and I tried to submit a third.  In this case, revoking one of the two active ones should allowed me to successfully submit a new one.